# Extract Multiple Embedded Images from a single PDF Page using PDFBox

Tags: java, image, pdf, pdfbox

Friends, I am using PDFBox 2.0.6. I have been successfull in extracting images from the pdf file, But right now it is creating an image for single pdf page. But the issue is that there can be any no. of images in a pdf page, And I want that each embedded image should be extracted as a single image itself.

Here is the code,

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer;

public class DemoPdf {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        //Loading an existing PDF document
        File file = new File("C:/Users/ADMIN/Downloads/Vehicle_Photographs.pdf");
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
        //Instantiating the PDFRenderer class
        PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
        File imageFolder = new File("C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/image");

        for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page) {
            //Rendering an image from the PDF document
            BufferedImage image = renderer.renderImage(page);
            //Writing the image to a file
            ImageIO.write(image, "JPEG", new File(imageFolder+"/" + page +".jpg"));
            System.out.println("Image created"+ page);
        }
        //Closing the document
        document.close();
    }

}
```

Is it possible in PDFBox that I can extract all embedded images as separate images, Thanks

Comment: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/tools/ExtractImages.java?view=markup

Comment: 2.0.7 has been released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to extract all images from all the pages in pdf.

You may refer this link, [extract images from pdf using PDFBox](https://www.tutorialkart.com/pdfbox/extract-images-from-pdf-using-pdfbox/).

The basic idea here is that, extend the class with PDFStreamEngine, and override processOperator method. Call PDFStreamEngine.processPage for all the pages. And if the object that has been passed to processOperator is an Image Object, get BufferedImage from the object, and save it.

Comment: Thanks, Malikarjun.It explained it all

Comment: Be aware that while the example is nicely written and the answer is good, it does not have the features of the official tool (see link in my other comment). The official tool avoids duplicates and can also detect inline images and save jpg files 1:1 as jpg.

Comment: The link has an error. It uselessly creates a BufferedImage object and assignes a new one directly afterwards.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. I have corrected the link and useless assignment to BufferedImage.

Answer (score 1):

Extend PDFStreamEngine and override the processOperator some thing like

```
 @Override
protected void processOperator( Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException
{
    String operation = operator.getName();
    if( "Do".equals(operation) )
    {
        COSName objectName = (COSName) operands.get( 0 );
        PDXObject xobject = getResources().getXObject( objectName );
        if( xobject instanceof PDImageXObject)
        {
            PDImageXObject image = (PDImageXObject)xobject;
            int imageWidth = image.getWidth();
            int imageHeight = image.getHeight();

            // same image to local
            BufferedImage bImage = new BufferedImage(imageWidth,imageHeight,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            bImage = image.getImage();
            ImageIO.write(bImage,"PNG",new File("c:\\temp\\image_"+imageNumber+".png"));

            imageNumber++;

        }
        else 
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {
        super.processOperator( operator, operands);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is similar with @jprism. But this is intended for someone who want just copy and paste this ready to use code with demo.

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.Operator;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSBase;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.PDXObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.form.PDFormXObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class ExtractImagesUseCase extends PDFStreamEngine{
    private final String filePath;
    private final String outputDir;

    // Constructor
    public ExtractImagesUseCase(String filePath,
                                String outputDir){
        this.filePath = filePath;
        this.outputDir = outputDir;
    }

    // Execute
    public void execute(){
        try{
            File file = new File(filePath);
            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);

            for(PDPage page : document.getPages()){
                processPage(page);
            }

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void processOperator(Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException{
        String operation = operator.getName();

        if("Do".equals(operation)){
            COSName objectName = (COSName) operands.get(0);
            PDXObject pdxObject = getResources().getXObject(objectName);

            if(pdxObject instanceof PDImageXObject){
                // Image
                PDImageXObject image = (PDImageXObject) pdxObject;
                BufferedImage bImage = image.getImage();

                // File
                String randomName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                File outputFile = new File(outputDir,randomName + ".png");

                // Write image to file
                ImageIO.write(bImage, "PNG", outputFile);

            }else if(pdxObject instanceof PDFormXObject){
                PDFormXObject form = (PDFormXObject) pdxObject;
                showForm(form);
            }
        }

        else super.processOperator(operator, operands);
    }
}
```

Demo

```
public class ExtractImageDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\John\\Downloads\\Documents\\sample-file.pdf";
        String outputDir = "C:\\Users\\John\\Downloads\\Documents\\Output";

        ExtractImagesUseCase useCase = new ExtractImagesUseCase(
                filePath,
                outputDir
        );
        useCase.execute();
    }
}
```